# NameError: global name 'is_sequence' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo

I have created the function **is_sequence(arg)** in the class **degree_day(osv.osv)**

When I call this function from the **write** function the system generates the error:

**NameError: global name 'is_sequence' is not defined**

I don't understand why the system is not finding this function.

```
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130520-231036\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\http.py", line 204, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130520-231036\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1130, in call_kw
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130520-231036\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1122, in _call_kw
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130520-231036\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 42, in proxy
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130520-231036\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130520-231036\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 103, in send


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130520-231036\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 89, in send
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130520-231036\Server\server\.\openerp\netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130520-231036\Server\server\.\openerp\service\web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130520-231036\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 188, in execute_kw
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130520-231036\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 131, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130520-231036\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 197, in execute
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130520-231036\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 185, in execute_cr
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130520-231036\Server\server\openerp\addons\degree_day\degree_day.py", line 187, in correct_future_degree_day
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130520-231036\Server\server\openerp\addons\degree_day\degree_day.py", line 79, in write
NameError: global name 'is_sequence' is not defined
```

degree_day.py

```python
from openerp.osv import osv, fields
from dateutil.parser import *
from dateutil.tz import *
from datetime import *


class degree_day(osv.osv):

    _name = "degree.day"
    _order = "date"
    _columns={
        'date': fields.date('Date'),
        'high_temp': fields.integer('High Temp'),
        'low_temp': fields.integer('Low Temp'),
        'heat_degree_day': fields.integer('Heat Degree Day' ),
        'hw_degree_day': fields.integer('Hot Water Degree Day' ),
        'state': fields.selection([
            ('normal','Normal'),
            ('initial_dd_adjust','Adjust Initial Degree Day')
            ], 'Status', readonly=True, track_visibility='onchange',
            help=' * The \'Normal\' status is used when a user is entering high and low temps and degree day values are readonly \
            \n* The \'Adjust Initial Degree Day\' status is used when a user is manually adjusting the first degree day records degree day values.'),
        'debug':fields.text('Debug text'),
        'initial_dd_record': fields.boolean("First DD Record"),
    }

    _defaults = {
        'state': lambda *a: 'normal',
    }

    def is_sequence(arg):
            return (not hasattr(arg, "strip") and
                hasattr(arg, "__getitem__") or
                hasattr(arg, "__iter__"))

    def write(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
        debug = '... '
        dd_recs = self.pool.get('degree.day')

        # were degree.day records retrieved?
        if dd_recs:
            debug += " dd_recs not null:" 

            # initial dd recs have dd values entered manually 
            # since there is no Day Before to draw from
            init_dd_rec = dd_recs.read(cr, uid, ids, ["initial_dd_record"])
            debug += "initial_dd_record="+str(init_dd_rec)+":"

            # sometimes this comes thorugh as a list and sometimes as single
            # convert to single if list
            if is_sequence(init_dd_rec):
                one_init_dd_rec = init_dd_rec[0]
            else:
                one_init_dd_rec = init_dd_rec

            # skip readonly override code if initial_dd_record is true
            # as all fields are readonly=False in this case
            if not one_init_dd_rec:
                debug += " not initial dd rec:" 

                # if high_temp not present, add it
                if not vals.has_key('high_temp'):
                    debug += " no high_temp:"
                    vals['high_temp'] = dd_recs.read(cr, uid, ids, ["high_temp"])[0]['high_temp']

                # if low_temp not present, add it
                if not vals.has_key('low_temp'):
                    debug += " no low_temp:"
                    vals['low_temp'] = dd_recs.read(cr, uid, ids, ["low_temp"])[0]['low_temp']

                vals['date'] = dd_recs.read(cr, uid, ids, ["date"])[0]['date']
                debug += " vals['date']="+vals['date']+":"
                debug += " dd_recs.read(cr, uid, ids, ['date'])=" +str(dd_recs.read(cr, uid, ids, ['date']))+":"

                # date seems to be stored as a string, so need to convert it before 
                # using it to find yesterdays date
                adate = parse(vals['date'])
                day_before = adate - timedelta(days=1)
                db_ids = dd_recs.search(cr, uid, [("date", "=", day_before)])

                # is there a record for yesterday?
                if db_ids:
                    debug += " ids not null:"
                    last_hdd = dd_recs.read(cr, uid, db_ids[0], ['heat_degree_day'])['heat_degree_day']
                    debug += " last_hdd="+str(last_hdd)+":"
                    last_hwdd = dd_recs.read(cr, uid, db_ids[0], ['hw_degree_day'])['hw_degree_day']
                    high_temp = vals['high_temp']
                    low_temp = vals['low_temp']
                    a = 65 - ((high_temp + low_temp)/2)
                    if a < 0:
                        a = 0
                    vals['heat_degree_day'] = a + last_hdd
                    vals['hw_degree_day'] = a + 5 + last_hwdd

        vals['debug'] = debug

        return super(degree_day, self).write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context=context)



    def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
        debug = '... '
        if vals.has_key('high_temp') and vals.has_key('low_temp'):
            adate = parse(vals['date'])
            day_before = adate - timedelta(days=1)
            dd_recs = self.pool.get('degree.day')
            # were any degree.day records retrieved?
            if dd_recs:
                debug += " dd_recs not null:" 
                ids = dd_recs.search(cr, uid, [("date", "=", day_before)])
                # is there a record for yesterday?
                if ids:
                    debug += " ids not null:"
                    last_hdd = dd_recs.read(cr, uid, ids[0], ["heat_degree_day"])
                    last_hwdd = dd_recs.read(cr, uid, ids[0], ["hw_degree_day"])
                    high_temp = vals['high_temp']
                    low_temp = vals['low_temp']
                    a = 65 - ((high_temp + low_temp)/2)
                    if a < 0:
                        a = 0
                    vals['heat_degree_day'] = a + last_hdd['heat_degree_day']
                    vals['hw_degree_day'] = a + 5 + last_hwdd['hw_degree_day']

        vals['debug'] = debug
        return super(degree_day, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)



    def correct_future_degree_day(self, cr, uid, ids, heat_degree_day, hw_degree_day, date, debug, context=None):
        """ when a degree days record is changed, all following records must be corrected
        @param high_temp: The day's high temperature
        @param low_temp: The day's low temperature
        """
        v={}
        debug = "... "

        dd_recs = self.pool.get('degree.day')
        if dd_recs:
            debug += " dd_recs not null:" 
            ids = dd_recs.search(cr, uid, [("date", ">=", date)], 0, None, "date")
            # are there records after this date?
            if ids:
                debug += " future records found:"
                running_hdd = heat_degree_day
                running_hwdd = hw_degree_day
                # cycle through each record recalculating degree day values
                for i in ids:
                    debug += "loop " + str(i) + ":"
                    low_temp = dd_recs.read(cr, uid, i, ["low_temp"])["low_temp"]
                    high_temp = dd_recs.read(cr, uid, i, ["high_temp"])["high_temp"]
                    # degree day calculation
                    a = 65 - ((high_temp + low_temp)/2)
                    if a < 0:
                        debug += " a<0:"
                        a = 0
                    running_hdd += a
                    running_hwdd += a + 5
                    update_dd = {"heat_degree_day":running_hdd, "hw_degree_day":running_hwdd}
                    dd_recs.write(cr, uid, i, update_dd, context=None)
                    debug += " done:"

        v['debug'] = debug
        return {'value':v}
```

degree_day_view.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="degree_day_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">degree.day.tree</field>
            <field name="priority" eval="1"/>           
            <field name="model">degree.day</field>
             <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Degree Day List">
                    <field name="date"  />
                    <field name="high_temp" />
                    <field name="low_temp" />
                    <field name="heat_degree_day"  /> 
                    <field name="hw_degree_day" />
                    <field name="state" invisible="True" />
                    <field name="debug" />
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="degree_day_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">degree.day.form</field>
            <field name="model">degree.day</field>
            <field name="priority" eval="2"/>           
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Degree Day" version="7.0">
                    <sheet string="Degree Day">
                        <h1>Day <field name="date" class="oe_inline"/></h1>
                        <group>
                            <field name="low_temp" readonly="False"/>
                            <field name="high_temp" readonly="False"/>
                        </group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="heat_degree_day" attrs="{'readonly': [('initial_dd_record','=',False)]}" on_change="correct_future_degree_day(heat_degree_day, hw_degree_day, date, debug)"/>
                            <field name="hw_degree_day" attrs="{'readonly': [('initial_dd_record','=',False)]}" on_change="correct_future_degree_day(heat_degree_day, hw_degree_day, date, debug)" />
                        </group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="initial_dd_record" />
                        </group>
                        <field name="state" invisible="True" />
                        <field name="debug" />
                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="show_degree_day" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Degree Day</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="degree_day_tree" />
            <field name="res_model">degree.day</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        </record>

        <menuitem id="degree_day_menu" name="Degree Day"/>
        <menuitem id="degree_day_main_menu" parent="degree_day_menu" name="Degree Day Menu" />

        <menuitem name="Degree Day List" id="menu_degree_day_list"  
            parent="degree_day_main_menu" action="show_degree_day"/>


    </data>

</openerp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are invoking the function without binding it to an instance of the degree_day class, you will need to invoke it with degree_day.is_sequence and pass an instance of degree_day as the first argument to the function.

However, it does not make much sense to restrict the scope of the function to the class without making it an instance method or a static method. If you need to make it a static method, decorate it with '@staticmethod'. If you need it to be an instance method, define it like the other methods below by passing self as the first argument.

```
So the two options are 
1) static method

@staticmethod
def is_sequence(arg):
    ...

2) Instance method

def is_sequence(self, arg):
    ...
```

In the first case, you can invoke it with degree_day.is_sequence. In the 2nd case, since you are calling from within another method, you can invoke it with self.is_sequence.

Comment: 3rd option is as falsetru suggested, get out of the class!

Comment: Thank you sir.  I need to study a bit as to why methods within the same class need to be qualified.  I am used to only having to qualify calls to methods outside of the class...

Comment: Whenever you define anything inside the class definition, it needs to be accessed with an instance. More on the scoping rules at http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks. So whether you are accessing it from a method or from anywhere outside does not matter to the python interpreter. Its by design that any attribute of the class needs to be accessed with a bound instance (or the class name). This helps with readability of the code. A reader can understand at first glance, that any variable referred to is an instance variable and not a local/global variable!

Answer (score 2):

Call `is_sequence(..)` as `self.is_sequence(..)`, and make `is_sequence` as staticmethod.

OR

Make `is_sequence` a function. (Get out of class).